# Prove closed set A is included in open set B

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm having real difficulty with vague concepts in my Introduction to Analysis course.

For example, I'm trying to approach this question:

***Let E be a metric space. Let A be a closed set in E. Prove there exists and open set B such that A is included in B.***

So from set theory I know that $A \epsilon E$. But intuitively, I'm thinking that that is so straight forward that I shouldn't need to write much and end up getting stuck.

Note: This is part of a longer problem related to topology and disjoint sets, however, I hesitate to post the whole question because I'd like to get a hint so I can solve it on my own as opposed to being given the solution.

Comment: Yes, it's trivial. Just use $B=E$. But note, you wrote $A \in  E$. That's not correct. It should be $A \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the text asks a question like this, it is teaching you how to do proofs.  This problem is of the form: Prove $A \subset B$.  You prove these problems by assuming $x \in A$ and then showing that $x \in B$.

This problem is also testing your understanding of open sets and what it means that the ambient space $X$ is a metric space.  Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and consider an epsilon-ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ for each $x \in A$.  Let $B=\cup_{x \in A}B_\epsilon(x)$.  $B$ is open because it is the union of open sets. Now let $x \in A$.  Then $x \in B$ because it's in one of the epsilon balls that are used to define $B$.  Thus $x \in B$

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just a side question: in the 3rd line of the second paragraph where you describe the union $x \epsilon A$, is there a particular reason that isn't the typical family of sets notation $i \epsilon I$?

Answer (score 2):

You can just take the whole space $X$. This is open by definition and every set in the metric space is contained in $X$.